# SQLITE3: Join based on timestamps

Tags: sqlite

In my SQLite3 database, I have 2 tables, one with timestamps and quantities and another one with timestamps and rates. The problem is "simple", I need to get the good prices according to the quantities and the updated rates.

Here an example of these 2 tables:

rates table (contains revisions of rates, eg rate has changed to 58.863 c$ from 17 Nov 2012 and until 16 Nov 2013, changed again on 17/11/2013 ...):

```
ts                 | cts
------------------------
2010-11-17 00:00:00|58.0
2011-11-17 00:00:00|58.636
2012-11-17 00:00:00|58.863
2013-11-17 00:00:00|59.120
...
```

production table (just took one day in 2012 but the table is covering 2010 up to now):

```
ts                 | qty
---------------------------------
...
2012-12-20 07:50:06|130
2012-12-20 08:00:05|130
2012-12-20 08:10:05|120
2012-12-20 08:20:04|130
2012-12-20 08:30:05|360
2012-12-20 08:40:05|230
2012-12-20 08:50:06|250
2012-12-20 09:00:05|310
2012-12-20 09:10:05|180
2012-12-20 09:20:06|270
2012-12-20 09:30:05|300
2012-12-20 09:40:06|290
2012-12-20 09:50:05|580
2012-12-20 10:00:05|260
2012-12-20 10:10:06|210
2012-12-20 10:20:06|350
2012-12-20 10:30:05|410
...
```

I need to get the correct rate according to the timestamp in the rates table and add a price column to my result

result of the query to set-up:

```
ts                 | qty | rate | price
---------------------------------
...
2012-12-20 07:50:06|130|58.863|7652.19 (qty * rate)
2012-12-20 08:00:05|130|58.863 ....
2012-12-20 08:10:05|120|58.863
2012-12-20 08:20:04|130|58.863
2012-12-20 08:30:05|360|58.863
2012-12-20 08:40:05|230|58.863
2012-12-20 08:50:06|250|58.863
2012-12-20 09:00:05|310|58.863
2012-12-20 09:10:05|180|58.863
2012-12-20 09:20:06|270|58.863
2012-12-20 09:30:05|300|58.863
2012-12-20 09:40:06|290|58.863
2012-12-20 09:50:05|580|58.863
2012-12-20 10:00:05|260|58.863
2012-12-20 10:10:06|210|58.863
2012-12-20 10:20:06|350|58.863
2012-12-20 10:30:05|410|58.863
...
```

My guess was to use LEAD function that appeared in last SQLite releases but I don't know of to use in a join.

```sql
SELECT * FROM production t1 
LEFT JOIN rates t2 ON t1.ts BETWEEN t2.ts AND LEAD(t2.ts,1,0) OVER (ORDER by t2.ts)
```

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LEAD():

```
select p.*, round(p.qty * r.rate, 2) price 
from production p inner join ( 
  select ts, rate, lead(ts) over (order by ts) nextts
  from rates  
) r on p.ts >= r.ts and (p.ts < r.nextts or r.nextts is null)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uVvkBUFyBYhtzEczFmCjzi/1).
Results:

```
| ts                  | qty | rate   | price    |
| ------------------- | --- | ------ | -------- |
| 2012-12-20 07:50:06 | 130 | 58.863 | 7652.19  |
| 2012-12-20 08:00:05 | 130 | 58.863 | 7652.19  |
| 2012-12-20 08:10:05 | 120 | 58.863 | 7063.56  |
| 2012-12-20 08:20:04 | 130 | 58.863 | 7652.19  |
| 2012-12-20 08:30:05 | 360 | 58.863 | 21190.68 |
| 2012-12-20 08:40:05 | 230 | 58.863 | 13538.49 |
| 2012-12-20 08:50:06 | 250 | 58.863 | 14715.75 |
| 2012-12-20 09:00:05 | 310 | 58.863 | 18247.53 |
| 2012-12-20 09:10:05 | 180 | 58.863 | 10595.34 |
| 2012-12-20 09:20:06 | 270 | 58.863 | 15893.01 |
| 2012-12-20 09:30:05 | 300 | 58.863 | 17658.9  |
| 2012-12-20 09:40:06 | 290 | 58.863 | 17070.27 |
| 2012-12-20 09:50:05 | 580 | 58.863 | 34140.54 |
| 2012-12-20 10:00:05 | 260 | 58.863 | 15304.38 |
| 2012-12-20 10:10:06 | 210 | 58.863 | 12361.23 |
| 2012-12-20 10:20:06 | 350 | 58.863 | 20602.05 |
| 2012-12-20 10:30:05 | 410 | 58.863 | 24133.83 |
```

Comment: Hello @forpas, super thanks for this query proposal, I adapted to my environment by casting ts to date only and it works as expected! You rock!